# How do I set up a keypress triggered by my mouse's position?

Tags: autohotkey

I have been playing a game that only uses LeftArrow/A (to walk left), RightArrow/D (to walk right), and shift (to sprint).  I am struggling to make a macro that will press left or right depending on my mouse's x coordinates, and sprint when my mouse is more towards the edges of my screen. To illustrate, think of the following variables (in parentheses) as different points across my screen, and the "|" as the edges:

|---Sprint Zone---(A)---Walk Zone---(B) No movement (C)---Walk Zone---(D)---Sprint Zone---|

If my x coordinate is less than A or greater than D, I want to send SHIFT+A or SHIFT+D (respectively)
If my x coordinate is between A & B or between C & D, I want to send A or D (respectively)
My deadzone will be between B and C.

Here is the code of my .ahk file:

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
SetTimer, Check, 20
return

Check:
;The following variables are the x-coordinates of my screen, which has a res of 3840x2160
a := 965
b := 1700
c := 2160
d := 2895
MouseGetPos, x, y
return
MouseLoop:
while (x < b || x > c) {
    MouseGetPos, x, y
    if (x > c) {
        if (x > d) {
            Send +d
            MouseGetPos, x, y
            goto, MouseLoop
        }
        else if (x <= d) {
            Send d
            MouseGetPos, x, y
            goto, MouseLoop
        }
        MouseGetPos, x, y
    }

    if (x < b) {
        if (x < a) {
            Send +a
            MouseGetPos, x, y
            goto, MouseLoop
        }
        else if (x >= a){
            Send a
            MouseGetPos, x, y
            goto, MouseLoop
        }
        MouseGetPos, x, y
    }
    if GetKeyState("Esc") {
        goto, Finished
    }
}
return
goto, MouseLoop

Finished:
Exit
```

Comment: Have you tried setting your script as `#Persistent`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using functions you always have a better overview, control and performance:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, Check, 20
return

Check:
If Zone("Sprint_Zone_1")
    ToolTip, "Sprint_Zone_1" ; send +a
else
If Zone("Walk_Zone_1")
    ToolTip, "Walk_Zone_1" ; send a
else
If Zone("Dead_Zone")
    ToolTip
else
If Zone("Walk_Zone_2")
    ToolTip, "Walk_Zone_2" ; send d
else
If Zone("Sprint_Zone_2")
    ToolTip, "Sprint_Zone_2" ; send +d
return

Zone(name){

    a := 965
    b := 1700
    c := 2160
    d := 2895

    CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
    MouseGetPos, mX

    Sprint_Zone_1 := (mX < a)
    Walk_Zone_1 := (mX > a && mX < b)
    Dead_Zone := (mX > b && mX < c)
    Walk_Zone_2 := (mX > c && mX < d)
    Sprint_Zone_2 := (mX > d)

    If (name = "Sprint_Zone_1")
        return Sprint_Zone_1
    else if (name = "Walk_Zone_1")
        return Walk_Zone_1
    else if (name = "Dead_Zone")
        return Dead_Zone
    else if (name = "Walk_Zone_2")
        return Walk_Zone_2
    else if (name = "Sprint_Zone_2")
        return Sprint_Zone_2
}

Esc:: 
    SetTimer, Check, off
    ToolTip
return
```

Comment: So I ran this code, and opened a text document, but is doesn't send a/+a or d/+d.  Do I have to take out the semicolons after the tooltips within the if statements?

Comment: ToolTip is only for demonstration purposes. Replace it with the appropriate Send command.